# How to create a program that check wheter the chess horse will be meet or not?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, chess

I have a question. How to make a program in c where the program will check whether the white horse and black horse on the chess board will meet or not, in this case it is recommended to use the recursive function. For example :

There is the chess board 8x8 :
[Chess Board Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDSHS.png)

The orange path is belong to horse 1, and the green path is belong to horse 2. The input will be one integer as the limit of horse movement and the second line will be the coordinates of both horses.

```
Input :
3 // this is the limit of knight can move
A1 H8 // this is the coordinates of both knights
Output :
YES, The Horses will Be Meet Each Other
```

Here is the code I tried to make :

```
#include "stdio.h"

int countMove = 0;
int flag[50][50] = {};
int i = 0;

int move(int x, int y,int Limit){
    flag[x][y] = 1;
    countMove++;

    if(countMove < Limit){
        move(x + 1, y + 2,Limit);
        move(x + 2, y + 1,Limit);
        move(x - 1, y - 2,Limit);
        move(x + 1, y - 2,Limit);
        move(x + 1, y + 2,Limit);
        move(x - 1, y + 2,Limit);
        move(x + 2, y - 1,Limit);
        move(x - 2, y + 1,Limit);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int testcase,walkLimit;
    char coordinates1[5][5],coordinates2[5][5];
    scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();

    for(i = 0; i <= testcase; i++){
        scanf("%d",&walkLimit); getchar();
        scanf("%s %s",coordinates1,coordinates2); getchar();

        int coordinatesX1 = 0,coordinatesX2 = 0;

        if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'A'){
            coordinatesX1 = 1;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'B'){
            coordinatesX1 = 2;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'C'){
            coordinatesX1 = 3;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'D'){
            coordinatesX1 = 4;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'E'){
            coordinatesX1 = 5;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'F'){
            coordinatesX1 = 6;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'G'){
            coordinatesX1 = 7;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'H'){
            coordinatesX1 = 8;
        }

        if(coordinates2[0][0] == 'A'){
            coordinatesX2 = 1;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'B'){
            coordinatesX2 = 2;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'C'){
            coordinatesX2 = 3;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'D'){
            coordinatesX2 = 4;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'E'){
            coordinatesX2 = 5;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'F'){
            coordinatesX2 = 6;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'G'){
            coordinatesX2 = 7;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][0] == 'H'){
            coordinatesX2 = 8;
        }

        int coordinatesY1,coordinatesY2 = 0;

        if(coordinates1[0][1] == '1'){
            coordinatesY1= 1;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '2'){
            coordinatesY1= 2;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '3'){
            coordinatesY1= 3;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '4'){
            coordinatesY1= 4;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '5'){
            coordinatesY1= 5;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '6'){
            coordinatesY1= 6;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '7'){
            coordinatesY1= 7;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '8'){
            coordinatesY1= 8;
        }

        if(coordinates1[0][1] == '1'){
            coordinatesY2= 1;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '2'){
            coordinatesY2= 2;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '3'){
            coordinatesY2= 3;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '4'){
            coordinatesY2= 4;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '5'){
            coordinatesY2= 5;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '6'){
            coordinatesY2= 6;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '7'){
            coordinatesY2= 7;
        } else if(coordinates1[0][1] == '8'){
            coordinatesY2= 8;
        }

        move(coordinatesX1,coordinatesY1,walkLimit);
        move(coordinatesX2,coordinatesY2,walkLimit);

        for(int k = 0; k <= 8; k++){
            for(int m = 0; m <= 8; m++){
                printf("%d\n",flag[k][m]); 
                }
            }

        flag[50][50] = {};
        countMove = 0;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And my code has no output, could you please help me?

Comment: Just a hint: You could skip the if-else with something like: `coordinatesX1=coordinates[0][0]-'A';`

Comment: Do you know why it has no output?

Comment: @user253751 I dont know, maybe my function has an infinite loop, but I dont know where is the mistake

Comment: The [knight's minimum moves are fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess)) relative to knight, so subtracting (two) offset bitmaps and looking for zero should give the minimum, (unless the knight has to backtrack; not sure about that.)

Answer (score 1):

Recommend a new approach:

1. Rather than counting moves, count iteration depth.
2. Only re-curse into empty squares.
3. Do not access `flag[][]` if indexes are out of range.  I think this is OP's main problem.

Example code (more like pseudo code)

```
#define WHITE 'W'
#define BLACK 'B'
#define EMPTY ' '
#define RANK_N 8
#define COLUMN_N 8

// return meet result
//
bool move(char flag[COLUMN_N][RANK_N], char team, int c, int r, int Limit) {
  if (Limit <= 0) return false;
  if (c < 0 || c >= COLUMN_N) return false; 
  if (r < 0 || r >= RANK_N) return false;

  if (flag[c][r] != EMPTY) {
    return flag[c][r] != TEAM; // paths crossed!
  }
  flag[c][r] = team;

  #define KNIGHT_MOVES 8
  int dr[KNIGHT_MOVES] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2};
  int dc[KNIGHT_MOVES] = { 1, 2,  2,  1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
  for (int i=0; i < KNIGHT_MOVES; i++) {
    if (move(flag, team, c + dc[i], r + dr[i], Limit - 1)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Set up the board as *empty*, try white, then black.

```
int main(void) {
  // get parameters with TBD code
  Limit = .... (1 == initial placement)
  r_start_wh = ...
  c_start_wh = ...
  r_start_bk = ...
  c_start_bk = ...

  char flag[COLUMN_N][RANK_N];
  memset(flag, EMPTY, sizeof flag); // set all squares to EMPTY

              move(flag, WHITE, c_start_wh, r_start_wh, Limit); // This never returns true
  bool meet = move(flag, BLACK, c_start_bk, r_start_bk, Limit);

  ... // print result.
}
```

Comment: I havent learn about define and bool in my college, so its make me hard to understand.. could you please give an alternative way?

Comment: or maybe explain it in other way, i really need it thanks:)

Comment: @FelixPrima `bool` is like an integer type with values 0 or 1 - used here as goal is "will meet or not".  `#define` is liek a text substitution.  Both of these are detailed in many web resources.

Comment: @FelixPrima, Seeking an "alternative way" is broad.  What specifically is unclear?

Comment: what is "TEAM" there? where should i define it?

Comment: hmm also when I try to submit it to online judge with my own way (after following ur pseudo code and try to suit it with my project) I only get 10/100 which only 1 testcase over 10 is true, is there any cases that it cannot reach? thx

Comment: @FelixPrima  "what is "TEAM" there?`"  --> is this black or white moving?

Comment: @FelixPrima Code's data co-ordinates are off by 1.  Array in C are indexed from 0, not 1.

Comment: @FelixPrima "I only get 10/100 which only 1 testcase over 10 is true, is there any cases that it cannot reach?" is insufficient.  What test case failed?  What were the staring co-ordinates? What was expected?  What happened?  If you cannot see the starting co-ordinates, try the code with your own set of inputs and see if it made expectations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203367/discussion-between-felix-prima-and-chux-reinstate-monica).